# change date and time format in php

Tags: php, web, mysqli

I am fetching time and date from MYSQLi using php. For time I am getting default 24 hr format and for date I am recieving format of y/m/d.

- I want to get time in 12 hr format.
- I want to get date in d/m/y format.

How to do it in php ?

Comment: check http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

In pure simple php, you can write as follow

Date

```
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($your_date));
```

Time

```
echo date('H:i', $your_time);
```

For the 12 hours, use

```
echo date('g:i A', $your_time);
```